# Change Simulated 3G Network For Lighthouse CLI

Tags: browser-automation, performance-testing

I'm having difficulty changing the network for Lighthouse. It is defaulting to 3G throttle.

Ideally, I would like to know how to run the performance audits without throttling.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the answer in this page.

```
--throttling-method=provided
```

[lighthouse status flags](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/v3/migration)